esbuild does not recognize module exports
I'm in the process of migrating a JS project from rollup to esbuild and I've hit a snag with one of the npm dependencies. Whenever my code imports a symbol from this library, esbuild outputs a warning like this:

Import "bar" will always be undefined because the file "node_modules/[path]/lib/index.js" has no exports [import-is-undefined]

If I try to load the bundle in a browser I get this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Unfortunately the library package is private so I can't link here.
The library's package.json contains these fields:
  "main": "lib",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "lib/*",
    "dist/*"
  ],

The .js files in lib/ define their exports like this:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Foo = void 0;
exports.Foo = {
  bar
}

function bar() {
  //...
}

And the generated code in the bundle that breaks in the browser looks like this:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });


Well that is a commonjs module, which does not have any export declarations. It looks though as if they were generating that by transpiling from ES6 (or TypeScript) source, so you should try to import that instead. (And file an issue with the library that they should start distributing their ES6 source and fix their package.json - having both /lib and /dist is suspicious)

esbuild should be able to bundle commonjs modules, it says so right on its home page. Not sure why it doesn't work in this case. The package doesn't contain the sources so I can't import those. The dist dir only contains assets like HTML files.

The problem is that it isn't treated as a commonjs module, because the package.json says "type": "module". The library authors will need to fix that, or better, publish an actual ES6 module with export declarations.
